# Adding values from one table to a new column in another table based on a similar ID in r

Tags: r

I have two tables in R

Table 1 is like this:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 22 |

Table 2 is like this:

| ID | Value | New |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |  |
| 2 | 20 |  |
| 3 | 30 |  |

I have made a new column called New in table 2.
I need to bring values from table 1 to table 2 using similar IDs in both tables.
My expected table should be like this:

| ID | Value | New |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 11 |
| 2 | 20 | 22 |
| 3 | 30 |  |

I need some codes to do this job in RStudio.
How can I do this?
I appreciate your help.

Comment: try `library(dplyr);inner_join(df1,df2, by = ID)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr::full_join` and `dplyr::rename`,

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,2),
  Value = c(11,22)
)
df2 <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,2,3),
  Value = c(10,20,30),
  New = c(NA,NA,NA)
)
df2 %>%
  full_join(df1,by = "ID") %>%
  select(-New) %>%
  rename(Value = Value.x, New = Value.y )

  ID Value New
1  1    10  11
2  2    20  22
3  3    30  NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer